# Why paraxial rays are used for image construction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I teach physics to high schoolers. Some days ago I read the following optics 
question in a physics book.

> Q. Why paraxial rays are used to study ray optics?

The answer given in the book is

> Since the paraxial rays are the only one ones which have single focus point 
>   and hence can form a clear image.

It is labeled correct.

Another option that was given and was labeled incorrect.

> Since they are easiest to handle.

I understand why the 'correct' option is correct but I think that at least one reason why we do the analysis is that it is easy to handle.

Is the other option really incorrect?

Comment: Of some interest here is an article in the November 2015 issue of *The Physics Teacher* (J.Marx and S.Mian, vol 53, no 8, pp 497--499) which discusses a construction for using arbitrary rays in optics diagrams.

Comment: @dmckee can suggest a way to get this article?

Comment: Try online? Ask you local college or university librarian? I get it as a paper copy as part of my membership in the American Association of Physics Teachers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, the approximations that you can make in the paraxial approximation are easier to handle, since you don't have to consider many of the aberrations that come about when dealing with lens systems.  But ease of use is not the main reason why it is used.  In the paraxial case, spherical aberrations of the lenses can be ignored, because the focal plane of all the rays is approximately the same.  In your equations, your angles are small, which makes $\sin(\theta)\sim \tan(\theta)\sim \theta$ and $\cos(\theta)\sim 1$.  This certainly simplifies things in your ray matrices, but the location of the image is better defined in the paraxial case.

The correct answer that was listed is certainly **more** correct than the other, even though the other answer is technically true.

Edit: I should also note, that experimentally, it helps you form clear images by cutting out high angle rays, so this does have practical application beyond just making the math easier.